# filtering an array of objects based on another array of values, returning an empty list

Tags: javascript

I am trying to filter an array of objects using another array of values, but I am getting an empty list. Below is my code

```
[{'id':1,name:'x1'},{'id':2,name:'x2'},{'id':3,name:'x3'}].filter(function(val){
        [1,2,3].forEach(function(id){
           if(id == val.id){
               return true;
           } 
        });
    });
```

My doubt is

1)It seems like the callback function of inner forEach doesnt returns the boolean to the parent callback function of filter. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: @squint I thought the return of forEach  bubbles up to the return of filter. Got my mistake now

Comment: It's a common mistake, but no. If it did, it would have a side effect of halting all functions in the call stack, which is usually not desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your filter function is returning nothing, so `undefined` is effectively `false`, which means it is excluded form the list. Your `return` statement only returns from the `forEach` callback.

Use [`.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `.forEach()`, and put a `return` statement before it.

```
[{'id':1,name:'x1'},{'id':2,name:'x2'},{'id':3,name:'x3'}].filter(function(val){
    return [1,2,3].some(function(id){
       if(id == val.id){
           return true;
       } 
    });
});
```

The `.some()` method returns `true` if at least 1 invocation of the callback returns a truthy value. It also halts the iteration as soon as a truthy value is returned.

---

FYI, you can shorten it a little by dropping the `if` statement.

```
[{'id':1,name:'x1'},{'id':2,name:'x2'},{'id':3,name:'x3'}].filter(function(val){
    return [1,2,3].some(function(id){
       return id == val.id
    });
});
```

---

Or even more by using the new arrow function syntax.

```
[{'id':1,name:'x1'},{'id':2,name:'x2'},{'id':3,name:'x3'}]
  .filter((val) => [1,2,3].some((id) => id == val.id));
```

---

Or since you don't need any complex logic to do the comparison, you can use the ES7 [`.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method, which returns a boolean result based on a strict equality comparison.

```
[{'id':1,name:'x1'},{'id':2,name:'x2'},{'id':3,name:'x3'}]
  .filter(function(val) { return [1,2,3].includes(val.id) });
```

or

```
[{'id':1,name:'x1'},{'id':2,name:'x2'},{'id':3,name:'x3'}]
  .filter((val) => [1,2,3].includes(val.id));
```

There's a polyfill in the linked docs to patch up older implementations that don't yet have `.indcludes()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{'id':1,name:'x1'},{'id':2,name:'x2'},{'id':3,name:'x3'}].filter(function(val){
        var returnValue = false;
        [1,2,3].forEach(function(id){
           if(id == val.id){
               returnValue = true;
           } 
        });
        return returnValue;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simple way using `Array.filter` and `Array.indexOf` functions:

```
var arr = [{'id':1,name:'x1'},{'id':2,name:'x2'},{'id':3,name:'x3'}];

arr = arr.filter(function(val){
    return [1,2,3].indexOf(val.id) !== -1;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4));
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "x1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "x2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "x3"
    }
]
```

Comment: agreed this is the best and simple option, my doubt was whether the return in forEach call back reaches the filter callback, @squint's comment and mohit's answer cleared my doubts.